# Global sprint capacity per team member?

Tags: azure-devops

A developer in my devops organisation doesn't work fulltime.

Is there a way to fill this in globally, or do I need to go to each sprint and choose his weekly day off durign this sprint? 
[image: Sprint Capacity overview]

As you can't choose days off outside of a sprint, You'll need to open every sprint, which looks like a bit of stupid work.

[image: End date of day offs must be within the timeframe of the sprint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Choose days off outside of a sprint.

You can achieve this with one extension: [Team Calendar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.team-calendar).

After install it in your org, you will see one tab **Calendar** in the left panel. Left click the relevant date, you will see "Add days off":

[image]

This won't be consider about the period of iteration. You can go directly to set the days off in the **Calendar**.

[image]

Comment: Looks great! Doesn't look like you can add a recurring event, but this is waay better!
Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome:-) Hope this can give you much help.